# Running Topcoder arena applet behind University firewall

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor, java-applet

I am posting this question here after redirection from stackoverflow. I don't know if it's appropriate or not but I'm dying to get a solution. In our University, connections to external IP through the non standard port is blocked as a result of which I can't run Top Coder arena applet by filling in the proxy details (We connect through proxy). I then have to use Tor to route the traffic through the socks for the applet. Here is what I do :

- Run tor and establish a network.
- Fill in socks and proxy details in Java Control Panel
- Run topcoder arena with values of socks proxy.

However, this thing doesn't work out all the time. It may connect today and may not for next week. I can see in Tor's view network area where it makes connection to TopCoder servers, but the connection closes. I have tried like thousands of times. Please help me. Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any alternatives on Ubuntu?